# How to merge dataframe rows to a single row with all row values concenated for each column?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, row

I have a df like:

```
  | col1  | col2   | col3
0 | Text1 | a,b ,c | klra-tk³,t54 ? 
1 | Text2 | NaN    | gimbal3, gimbal4
2 | Text3 | a,k,m  | NaN
```

I want to get a single row with all unique values of a column in a single line and NaNs ignored like:

```
  | col1                | col2      | col3
0 | Text1, Text2, Text3 | a,b,c,k,m | klra-tk³,t54,gimbal3, gimbal4
```

How can I do this with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom function with [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), reove duplicates by [`Series.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) and remove missing values by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html), last join by `,` and convert `Series` to one row DataFrame by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose:

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(x.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().drop_duplicates().dropna())
df = df.apply(f).to_frame().T
print (df)
                col1       col2                         col3
0  Text1,Text2,Text3  a,b,c,k,m  klra-tk,t54,gimbal3,gimbal4
```

Or use list comprehension like:

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(x.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().drop_duplicates().dropna())
df = pd.DataFrame([[f(df[x]) for x in df.columns]], columns=df.columns)
```